# How does npm manage transitive modules?

Tags: node.js, npm

If I have an A module in my application which uses a C module in version 1 and a B module that also uses this C module but in version 2, which version of C module my project will actually be using?

Something like below:

```
My project
|--- A module
     |--- C module version 1
|--- B module
     |--- C module version 2
```

Comment: Both of C versions would be installed

Comment: And are those both C module versions available to be used by my own source-code in my project or only for my modules? If I do need to have C module available to me I can rely on one of those versions (and which one?) or do I have to explicitly declare one of my own?

Comment: You need to declare yours explicitly in you `package.json` file as a dependency or peers.Yes, you can use inner modules on your project but honestly I don't know about side effects at all and don't recommend this approach

Comment: You should add these informations you provided into your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `npm install` npm looks for `package.json` dependencies and peers recursively and install them all in their own folders. and if two dependencies have same dependency with different semantic version you would have both of versions but in different folders.
For example in a project you might have about 20 thousand dependencies and all of them are installed by `npm` on node_module folder and that's why the folder is soooo big.

Answer (score 1):

No. You no need to care about sub node_module inside A module or B module. What you should care is how to use module A and B.
Unless you want to use module C in side your code, u must install it independently. For example:

```
npm install C
```

In this case all module A, B and C are folders which same level.

```
node_module/
---Module A
     |---Module C (1)
---Module B
     |---Module C (2)
---Module C (*)
```

Summary: module C (*) is different with Module C (1) and (2). Maybe same version or different version.

Comment: And are those both C module versions available to be used by my own source-code in my project or only for my modules? If I do need to have C module available to me I can rely on one of those versions (and which one?) or do I have to explicitly declare one of my own?

Comment: when u use: **const moduleC = require("C")**, that's mean u reference to module C (*). Its version depends on your command to install it.

Comment: I didn't understand your last comment.